# gnuplot - cannot place the key using the at-attribute

Tags: bar-chart, gnuplot

I have this "MWE"

```
set title font "Monospaced,13" 'Total duration'
set grid
set style data histograms
set style histogram cluster 
set style fill solid
set xtics format ""
set grid ytics
set ylabel "Milliseconds"

AddFirstColor    = "#491d75";
AddLastColor     = "#b32929";
RemoveFirstColor = "#d49435";
RemoveLastColor  = "#12520b";

set yrange[0:16000]
set ylabel "Milliseconds"

set key at 1.9,2.5 opaque box lc "black" linewidth 3 spacing 1.2 box opaque fillcolor "grey"

plot 'data.dat' using 2:xtic(1) title "Add first" linecolor rgb AddFirstColor, \
             '' using 3 title "Add last" linecolor rgb AddLastColor, \
             '' using 4 title "Remove first" linecolor rgb RemoveFirstColor, \
             '' using 5 title "Remove last" linecolor rgb RemoveLastColor, \
             '' u 0:1:1 with labels offset -6.0,-100.0 title ""

set terminal png size 650,350 enhanced font "Monospaced,13"
set output 'data.png'
replot
exit
```

The `data.dat` contains:

```
#                 AddFirst AddLast RemoveFirst RemoveLast
"Linked list"     6841     6675    1189        1042
"Circular list"   7037     9703    2546        2332
```

The output is:

[image: Bad output]

I wish to place the key box on top right such that it is (say) 5 pixels from the top line of the plot and 5 pixels from the right verical line. How could I achieve that?

**Edit: extending the question**

Now I have two graphs:

`AddAtBeginning.png`:

[image]

and

[image]

As you can see, the key box is anchored to the left top corner differently in the above two graphs: the horizontal distances from the key box and the y-axis do not match. I need to make them equidistant. (I suppose it is due to the fact that the two plots have the y-label area of different sizes, since we are dealing with different scales.) Also, it would be nice if the plot boxes had similar geometry (same dimensions, same position relative to entire .png file) (this might or might not solve my issue automatically).

`AddAtBeginning.plt` is given by:

```
set xlabel 'Size'
set ylabel 'Microseconds'   
set xrange [0:1000000]

plot 'AddAtBeginning.dat' index 0 title "Array list", \
     ''                   index 1 title "Indexed list", \
     ''                   index 2 title "Linked list", \
     ''                   index 3 title "Tree list

set terminal png background rgb "grey" size 650,350 enhanced font "Monospaced,13"
set output 'AddAtBeginning.png'

set style rect fc rgb "white" fs
set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind
set key at graph 0.425,0.97 box lt -1 lw 2 opaque

replot
exit
```

Also, `AddAtEnd.plt` is given by:

```
set xlabel 'Size'
set ylabel 'Microseconds'   
set xrange [0:1000000]

plot 'AddAtEnd.dat' index 0 title "Array list", \
     ''             index 1 title "Indexed list", \
     ''             index 2 title "Linked list", \
     ''             index 3 title "Tree list

set terminal png background rgb "grey" size 650,350 enhanced font "Monospaced,13"
set output 'AddAtEnd.png'

set style rect fc rgb "white" fs
set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind
set key at graph 0.425,0.97 box lt -1 lw 2 opaque

replot
exit
```

[image: fds]

In the above image, I need to anchor the red area statically to the entire `.png` file (the green box) dimensions, and I need to anchor the violet key box statically relative to the red graph border.

Comment: Where do you actually want to place your key box? Which coordinate system? First, graph or screen? Check `help key placement`. Your y-coordinate is 2.5 that's what you are telling gnuplot and that's where gnuplot places it.

Comment: @theozh Rephrased my question.

Comment: Now it's getting clearer. Try to minimize your MWEs, e.g. fancy linestyles and detailed data, etc. are not relevant to the problem here. So, to summarize: you want your legend box in a fixed pixel distance from the corner. You basically said this in your original question but not mentioning that you have different graphs with different sizes. If you place it relative to the graph, the placement of course depends on the size and the aspect ratio of the graph. I see 3 options: 1. place it exactly on the corner, 2. make all graphs the same size, 3. lengthy workaround to get your pixel distance.

Comment: Do all your plots have the same range for the x-axes? And only the y-axes have different ranges?

Comment: @theozh Same range for x-axis (100_000, 200_000, ..., 1_000_000). Y-axes vary from plot to plot.

Comment: @theozh I think I finally managed to properly phrase my question. Please see the end of my quesion.

Comment: OMG, again another unmentioned detail... that's what I meant above with option 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always check gnuplot help before asking questions! There is to almost every keyword an entry `help <keyword>`.
Here, it would have been `help key` or in newer versions `help key placement`.

There are different coordinate systems, check `help coordinates`, but as far as I know no pixel coordinate system.

But something like the following should do the job:

```
set key at graph 0.995,0.99
```

**Addition:**

That's what I finally understood from your revised question: you want place the key box in a fixed (pixel) distance from a corner of a graph, ***independent*** of the graph size. If your x-range is the same for all graphs you could use `first` for the x-position and `graph` for the variable y-range.
Although, depending on the y-labels and y-tics, you could also set the same left margin and ensure the same size and aspect ratio for all plots. Then graph coordinates would be constant and independent of x- and y-range.

There is also a way to set it in a fixed pixel distance independent of graph size *and* x,y-ranges. However, this would be a cumbersome solution requiring replotting. If you're really interested let me know.

**Script:**

```
### place legend box at distance from corner "almost" independent of graph size
reset session

set key left box width 1
set key at first 10000, graph 0.97
set tics out

set multiplot layout 2,1

    set xrange[0:1e6]
    set yrange[0:10]
    set ylabel "some label"

    plot 1e-5*x, 2e-5*x, 3e-5*x w l

    set yrange[0:1000000]
    set ylabel "some multiline\nlabel\n with 3 lines" offset -1.5,0
    plot x, 2*x, 3*x w l

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition 2:**

So, after all, it seems you were just looking for constant margins for all graphs, e.g. `set margins 20,5,10,10`, check and read `help margins`. If the graphs have the same size, the position of your key box will be identical if you use `graph` coordinates. I hope, this will answer your question unless you have another unmentioned requirement.

**Script:**

```
### place legend box at distance from corner
reset session

set key left box width 1
set key at graph 0.01, graph 0.97
set tics out
set margins 20,5,10,10   # l,r,b,t

set multiplot layout 2,1

    set xrange[0:1e6]
    set yrange[0:10]
    set ylabel "some label"
    plot 1e-5*x, 2e-5*x, 3e-5*x w l

    set yrange[0:1000000]
    set ylabel "some multiline\nlabel\n with 3 lines" offset -1.5,0
    plot x, 2*x, 3*x w l

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: How can I "anchor" the key box to a position *relative* to the actual plot area and not the entire `data.png`? Idea is to exclude the x/y-label areas from consideration.

Comment: @coderodde Please *read* ` help key` *carefully*. There are coordinate systems, e.g. `first, graph, screen`. `first` is axis coordinates, `graph` is plotting area, `screen` is full canvas. Then there are alignment options `left, center, right, bottom, top`. Please RT*M!

Comment: `set key at graph 0.995,0.99` does not cut it, since I have another similar gnuplot script whose y-label requires different width from what is evident in my script above., and so that other key box does not "anchor" the same way.  I accepted, however, your answer because you almost near the solution to my issues. Finally, I RT*M and tried `first, second, graph, screen, character`, all one by one, yet I am still not quite there.

Comment: @coderodde I don't know what your "other similar" gnuplot script is. If it is important for the question, please add it to the question. Again, where do you want to have the anchor point with respect to the box and where do you want to have this anchor point with respect to the axes, graph or screen? If you cannot express it in clear words, please add a handsketch!

Comment: Fair enough. Should I extend my question right here, or does it warrant a new question?

Comment: @coderodde edit your question and add a handsketch how you would like it or alternatively add the "other similar" plot and describe what you want to change.

Comment: I have extended my question. If anything is obscure, let me know. Thanks.